'{% load static %}' doesn't seem to get picked up by vs code
enter image description here
The text is still white and there's no indicator as to if it's working or not.
I don't know if this is because of a screw up in my part or an issue with VS code.
I am unfamiliar with troubleshooting methods for this, please let me know if there are any.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Very likely Visual Code indeed doesn't understand Django's template syntax.

Follow these steps:

Download Django extension in vs code
Install and enable it
Restart your vs code

these suggestions can help
